# How to detect that a mailto event has been triggered?

Tags: javascript, iframe, mailto

I'm using an iframe to open the user's email client since I don't want to set the window's own location.

```js
var body = document.querySelector("#body");
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = "mailto:sample@email.com";
body.appendChild(iframe);
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```

I tried defining an `onload` function for `iframe` but it doesn't seem that it's ever called due to the `src` being a `mailto`.

I'm wondering if there's any other event that might indicate I can go and remove the iframe.

Comment: Why not just create an `a` and set it's `href` to `mailto:`? Then you can set up an event handler for the `click` event.

Comment: `mailto:sample@email.com` is an action not a src or location.